# Building bash array from AWK

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to build a bash array to hold a series of links. I use AWK to get the name and href attributes from a links.csv file [ column 2 and column 4, respectively ]. The CSV files holds information for 13 links.

```
arrayLinks=($(awk -F, 'NR>2 {printf("\"<a name=%s href=%s target=_blank>\" \n", $2, $4)}' $linksPath))
```

If I run only the AWK part in my console, I get something like this:

```
"<a name=name1 href=href1 target=_blank>"
"<a name=name2 href=href2 target=_blank>"
"<a name=name3 href=href3 target=_blank>"
"<a name=name4 href=href4 target=_blank>"
```

Which is exactly what I want. However, if I run the code in my bash script, instead of getting an array of 13 elements, I get an array with many much more elements [ it appears the space acts as an element delimiter ].

```
echo "Number of items in original array: ${#arrayLinks[*]}"
```

I'm getting 52 results while I was expecting only 13! What do I do wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Add your script and file `$linksPath` to your question.

Comment: Count the number of spaces in each element. Your approach won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that it seems unlikely that there will be any newline characters in your output, you should use `readarray` instead of relying on word-splitting.

```
readarray -t arrayLinks < <(
  awk -F, 'NR > 2
           {
             printf("\"<a name=%s href=%s target=_blank>\" \n", $2, $4)
           }
  ' "$linksPath"
)
```

(Line breaks are for readability only; you can collapse this to a single line if you like.)

The problem is, when the command substitution is expanded, *every* whitespace in the output is used to split the result into words. The quotes are simply part of the output, not syntactic quotes that protect the whitespace.

The `readarray` command, on the other hand, uses exactly one line of input (with no word splitting) for each element of the array. (If you are using `bash` 4.4 or later, you can have `awk` write null-delimited output instead, and use `-d` to tell `readarray` how to split its input into array elements.)

Comment: This is actually working very smooth and does exactly what I was expecting! Thank you very much!!!!!!